# EventMachine Deferrable callback chain

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I have some Deferrables, and I need to do something in callback when all of them are completed.

```
defers[0].callback do
    defers[1].callback do
        defers[2].callback do
            yield if block_given?
        end
    end
end
```

But this is very ugly and I have to know the exact number of necessary callbacks.
How can I write it the cleaner way?

Like in jQuery, `$.when` allows passing of an array of `$.Deferred` objects, this would be awesome, can I do it in Ruby?

```
$.when(defers).done(function() {
    // do something
})
```

I can't use em-synchrony because of using incompatible libraries.

---

Solution:

```
multi = EventMachine::MultiRequest.new
defers.each.with_index do |defer, i|
    multi.add(i, defer)
end
multi.callback do
    yield if block_given?
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `em-http-request` gem you can use [`EventMachine::MultiRequest`](http://rdoc.info/github/igrigorik/em-http-request/master/EventMachine/MultiRequest).

If not, the implementation is easy [`em-http-request / lib / em-http / multi.rb`](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/blob/master/lib/em-http/multi.rb) so make your own.

Comment: Thanks, It looks I can use MultiRequest directly as it doesn't contain any http-request related code, just handling callbacks.